# Is there a way to change the style of a div's :after psuedoelement when hovering over it's :before psuedoelement?

Tags: html, css, hover

Given the following css:

```
.myDiv:before{
    content:'';
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    display:block;
}

.myDiv:after{
   ...
   ...
   display:none;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class='myDiv'></div>
```

Is there a way to show the .myDiv:after psuedoelement while hovering over the :before? I know I can use the hover selector as .myDiv:hover:before but I don't know how to access the :after psuedoelement from within that selector.

Comment: no, pseudo-element belongs to their parents, so when you hover the pseudo-elements you hover the whole parent.

Comment: The short answer is no. pseudo-elements cannot be targeted with pseudo-class selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new style to display the content in the `:after`  css class although it may not be the best practice.

```
.myDiv:hover:after {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gk7R2/1/

Answer (score 0):

The only close way that you can do it is if you hover the entire element like this:

```
.myDiv {
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
}
.myDiv:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
.myDiv:hover:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/W4ca3/

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to trigger the :hover::after from executing a :hover::before. You can solve this problem with javascript though.  If you're wanting to maintain a clean markup, you could create a loop within this fiddle and dynamically add placeholders behind the pseudo elements so that you can interact with them instead of trying to access pseudo elements that do not exist in the DOM.

```
$("head").append("<style id='pseudoElementStyle'></style>");

var setPseudoElementDisplay = function (hover) {
    var content = hover ? ' after' : '';
    var cssRule = '.text::after { content: "' + content + '"; }';
    $('#pseudoElementStyle').text(cssRule);
};

$('.text').prepend('<span class="place-holder before">before </span>');
$('.text').append('<span class="place-holder after"> after</span>');

$('.place-holder').each(function () {
    var direction;
    var width = $(this).css('width');
    direction = $(this).hasClass('before') ? 'left' : 'right';
    $(this).css('margin-' + direction, '-' + width);
});

$('.before').mouseover(function () {
    setPseudoElementDisplay(true);
}).mouseout(function () {
    setPseudoElementDisplay(false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonjohnson115/2d96N/